# how to solve ambiguous reference between two namespaces in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing in Unity with the .NET Framework.

I'm using `List<string>` a lot. Suddenly, today I got message that there is ambiguous between `zenject.List<t>` and `System.Collections.Generic.List<t>`.

When I clicked "yes", it changed all `List<string>` instances to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`.

I don't want to use list of Zenject at all. And I prefer not to write the full `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` every time I need a list.

Is there an option to configure that all `List<string>` will be related to the generic namespace by default?

I tried to write

```
using List = System.Collections.Generic;
```

but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your using alias misses a type in its declaration

```
using GenericListOfStrings = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;

var strings = new GenericListOfStrings();
```

I am not familiar with Zenject, but the better approach IMO would be to encapsulate all usages of Zenject in a class, so you don't need that namespace in your source code

For example,

```
using Zenject;

namespace Zenject // imagine this code in a third party library
{
    class SomeZenjectClass { }
}

namespace YourCode
{
    class ZenjectContainer
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            var obj = new SomeZenjectClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your code can exclude conflicting namespace

```
using YourCode;

var zenject = new ZenjectContainer();
var list = new List<string>(); // I can use lists!
```